# Align problem in Bmatrix

Tags: align, matrices

My latex code is like:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{a, b}{argmax}= &
\begin{bmatrix*} 
t(a,b,c) u_1(a)+ t(a,b) u_1(a) & [c] \\
t(a,b,c u_1(a) & [d] \\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{eqnarray*}\\
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{a, b}{argmax}= &
\begin{bmatrix*}
0.9 u_1(a)+ 0.1 u_1(b) & [c] \\
1 u_1(a) & [d] \\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

when I compile it, it is like

[image]

How can I align all argmaxes in horizontal line?

Comment: Your code was garbled while posting, lots of missing `\ ` and strange non-printing control characters. I fixed it up a bit but all examples should really be complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so people can run them to reproduce the problem. Also I used the `{}` button to mark the code section (it indents by four spaces)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\argmax_{a,b} &=
  \begin{bmatrix*} 
    t(a,b,c) u_1(a)+ t(a,b) u_1(a) & [c] \\
    t(a,b,c u_1(a) & [d] \\
  \end{bmatrix*}\\[1ex]
\argmax_{a,b} &=
  \begin{bmatrix*}
    0.9 u_1(a)+ 0.1 u_1(b) & [c] \\
    1 u_1(a) & [d] \\
  \end{bmatrix*}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```